# How to get average value using aggregation in Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a Mongoose schema, where one of the properties is defined as follows:

```
// Partially removed for brevity.
const recommendationsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ratings: [{ category: String, rating: Number }],
}, {
  timestamps: true
});
```

And now I want to get the total number of entries in my collection, and also the average for ratings. But, I want to get average only for ratings where `category` field is equal to `total`. So something like `{ category: 'total' }`.

I tried to do something like this but doesn't seem to work:

```
[
    {
        $count: "total_count",
        $group: {
            avg: { $avg: $ratings.rating }
        }
    }
]
```

The `count` field seems to return the total entries in the collection, which is good and what I want. But, how can I get the average of ratings where `{ category: 'total' }`? So, I just want to return two fields, `total_count` and `average`. Any ideas how to achieve this in Mongoose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$facet": {
    "totalCount": [{ "$count": "count" }],
    "averagteRating": [
      { "$match": { "ratings.category": "total" } },
      { "$unwind": "$ratings" },
      { "$match": { "ratings.category": "total" } },
      { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "averageRating": { "$avg": "$ratings.rating" }
      }}
    ]
  }}
])
```